# Where are any army base locations that I can loot?

Tags: fallout-4

Are there any good Army bases that have ammo, medical supplies, and power armor?

If so, where are they located?

Comment: another question is the Marine Assault Armor Set dlc only

Comment: There's an answer. It occurred to me after I wrote it that I'm not sure what you mean by "good" Army bases. Please let me know if that's not quite what you were looking for.

Comment: DcShannon your good

Comment: @Robert__garnet I've noticed that you haven't accepted an answer for any of your questions. If an answer fully answers your question, you should click the check mark beside that answer so that the question is marked as closed and people who have the same question in the future can see it and know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several military locations with power armor throughout the Commonwealth. Not all of them are named locations with fast travel waypoints. For example, there is a crashed vertibird with a suit of power armor next to it west of USAF Satellite Station Olivia. I'll list a few of these of which I'm aware, but I don't know of any list to reference to find the other ones.

Below is a list of power armor locations in the Commonwealth that are associated with the military. Ammo and medical supplies can be found in random containers, so there may be some there whether any is listed on the wiki or not, but I'll list any noted on the wiki.

**Named Locations**

1. [Federal Ration Stockpile](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Federal_Ration_Stockpile)

There's power armor in the green container in front of the stockpile. There are a lot of supplies throughout the area. I'm sure you'll find ammo and medicine.

[image: Federal Ration Stockpile]

2. [Federal Surveillance Center K-21B](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Federal_Surveillance_Center_K-21B)

There's power armor at the bottom of the silo. You can get ammo off the synths, if nothing else. Probably some medicine.

[image: Federal Surveillance Center K-21B]

3. [Fort Hagen Hangar](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fort_Hagen_hangar)

This is found in the Automatron DLC. There's a suit of leveled power armor between two expert locked gates, between the tank room and shelved radioactive barrels. There are some mini-nukes and a Fat Man, so that's ammo. No idea if there's any medicine.

[image: Fort Hagen Hangar]

4. [Fort Strong](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fort_Strong)

Part of this area can't be entered until you initiate a specific quest for the Brotherhood. There's power armor in the small guardhouse before the bridge to Fort Strong, so it's not actually inside. Inside you will definitely find ammo and I'm pretty sure there's some medicine in there as well.

[image: Fort Strong]

5. [National Guard Training Yard](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/National_Guard_Training_Yard)

There are two different power armor suits here.  On the western side of the area, outside, behind an expert locked security gate is one. There is an armory outside the main building, to the northwest. Inside, behind the terminal-locked door, you'll find another suit. There are enough containers in the main building I'm sure you'll find some ammo and medicine.

[image: National Guard Training Yard]

6. [Revere Satellite Array](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Revere_satellite_array)

I'm not 100% sure that this is actually a military installation, but it could be. One of the satellite dishes has stairs going all the way to the top. There's a power armor frame up here, but no pieces on it. The super mutants should have ammo on them. Not sure if you'll find any medicine.

[image: Revere Satellite Array]

7. [South Boston Military Checkpoint](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/South_Boston_Military_Checkpoint)

Behind the structure is a full suit of power armor behind an Expert terminal. I think I recall a first aid box on the wall. There's a locked safe inside, which should probably have ammo in it.

[image: South Boston Military Checkpoint]

**Other Places**

These are basically just off the top of my head. If anyone knows somewhere I could look for a better list, or has another to add, please leave a comment.

1. Crashed Vertibird

There's a crashed vertibird with a suit of power armor near it west of USAF Satellite Station Olivia.

2. South Boston Road Checkpoint

I recall finding a rusting suit of power armor southwest of the South Boston Military Checkpoint, along the road, near some personnel carriers.

3. Natick Road Checkpoint

I recall finding a rusting suit of power armor along the southern part of the road that runs west of Lake Cochituate, near some personnel carriers.

Comment: If mods are an option [this 4K color map](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/7169/) shows magazines, bobbleheads, and power armor in the map display.

Comment: My source of power armor are BOS Knights... I make a low damage Auto pistol and shoot out their batteries.  A VAT attack with an automatic weapon is 3 rounds, which is usually enough to set it off, but not enough to piss them off...

Comment: @Nelson You attack the Brotherhood? I SHALL HUNT YOU DOWN TRAITOR!!!!!

Comment: I attack everyone.  If you give me exp, and doesn't have a name, I kill you  :P